# Lines generated with TikZ intersections are too short

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

My script calculates several intersections of lines (green) with a vertical "wall" (not shown). The intersections (small red dots) are fine. But the lines from one intersection to another intersection are too short (blue). I don't have any idea what's wrong with the script:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\wallx{6cm}
        \def\scannerx{0cm}
        \def\scannery{0.0cm}
        \def\scannerradius{0.4cm}
        \def\walllength{8cm}

        \coordinate (WALLBEGIN) at ($(\wallx, 0.5*\walllength)$);
        \coordinate (WALLEND) at ($(\wallx, -0.5*\walllength)$);
        \coordinate (SCANNER) at (\scannerx, \scannery);
        \path[name path=wall] (WALLBEGIN) -- (WALLEND);

        %calculate intersections
        \foreach \index in {0,...,4} {
            %calculates the ray from scanner to wall
            \def\raylength{12cm}
            \coordinate (REL) at ({9*(\index-2)+1}:\raylength);
            \coordinate (RAYEND) at ($(SCANNER)+(REL)$);
            \path [name path=ray] (SCANNER) -- (RAYEND);

            %intersection with wall
            \path [name intersections={of=ray and wall,by=X}];
            \node (iwall\index) at (X) {};

            %THIS INTERSECTION IS OK
            \filldraw[fill=red] (X) circle (0.05cm);
            \draw[green] (SCANNER) -- (RAYEND);
        }


        % LINE BETWEEN TWO INTERSECTIONS WHICH IS TOO SHORT
        \draw[blue] (iwall0) -- (iwall1);

        \filldraw[fill=gray!50!white] (SCANNER) circle (\scannerradius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just using `\coordinate (iwall\index)` instead of `\node` fixes the problem. `coordinate` nodes don't take up any space, while empty `node`s still have the white space caused by the `inner sep`.

Comment: Or if you want to add some material to the node you can use: `\draw[blue] (iwall0.center) -- (iwall1.center);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding `node`s to save the intersection coordinates, you can just use `\path [name intersections={of=ray and wall,by=X\index}];`. The intersections will then be available as `X0`, `X1`, and so forth.

You could then "overwrite" these coordinates with circular nodes with an `inner sep=0pt`: the `inner sep` of your empty nodes caused the problem with the "detached" lines. They weren't actually deteched, they connected with the invisible border of your empty nodes.

In general, empty `node`s aren't the best thing to use if you just want to save a point, since even empty `node`s take up space (caused by the `inner sep`, which you could set to zero as a workaround). `\coordinate` (or, equivalently, `\node [coordinate]` are better for this task.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\wallx{6cm}
        \def\scannerx{0cm}
        \def\scannery{0.0cm}
        \def\scannerradius{0.4cm}
        \def\walllength{8cm}

        \coordinate (WALLBEGIN) at ($(\wallx, 0.5*\walllength)$);
        \coordinate (WALLEND) at ($(\wallx, -0.5*\walllength)$);
        \coordinate (SCANNER) at (\scannerx, \scannery);
        \path[name path=wall] (WALLBEGIN) -- (WALLEND);

        %calculate intersections
        \foreach \index in {0,...,4} {
            %calculates the ray from scanner to wall
            \def\raylength{12cm}
            \coordinate (REL) at ({9*(\index-2)+1}:\raylength);
            \coordinate (RAYEND) at ($(SCANNER)+(REL)$);
            \path [name path=ray] (SCANNER) -- (RAYEND);

            %intersection with wall
            \path [name intersections={of=ray and wall,by=X\index}];

            % use a circular node for drawing the circles
            \node [draw,fill=red,circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt] (X\index) at (X\index) {};
            \draw[green] (SCANNER) -- (RAYEND);
        }


        \draw[blue] (X1) -- (X2);

        \filldraw[fill=gray!50!white] (SCANNER) circle (\scannerradius);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you for your anwswer. It fixed my problem and now I understand what's the difference between nodes and coordinates.